# How to select a cell in QTableWidget programmatically

Tags: pyqt5

I have an object of QTableWidget. Whenever, I click on a cell of the table, it becomes blue. How can I make a cell blue, say the cell located at row 1 and column 1, programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [`selectionModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel):

```py
row = 1
column = 1
index = table_widget.model().index(row, column)
table_widget.selectionModel().select(
    index, QItemSelectionModel.Select | ItemSelectionModel.Current
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Are there any references to some sources I can study? I could not find this solution via the docs and I am wondering how I can find similar solutions next time on I my own.

Comment: @MOON You have to read the documentation of all the members of the class and also of the classes from which it inherits, in this case from QAbstractItemView: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel